# Excel VBA - For Each loop is not running through each cell

Tags: vba, formula

I am currently facing an issue in which my 'for each' loop is not moving onto subsequent cells for each cell in the range I have defined when I try to execute the script. The context around the data is below:

I have 3 columns of data. Column L contains employees, Column K contains managers, and column J contains VPs. Column K & J containing managers and VPs are not fully populated - therefore, I would like to use a VBA script & Index Match to populate all the cells and match employees to managers to VPs.

I have created a reference table in which I have populated all the employees to managers to directors and have named this table "Table 4". I am then using the VBA code below to try and run through each cell in column K to populate managers:

```
Sub FillVPs()
Dim FillRng As Range, FillRng1 As Range, cell As Range

Set FillRng = Range("J2:J2000")
Set FillRng1 = Range("K2:K2000")

For Each cell In FillRng1
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        ActiveCell.Formula = _
    "=INDEX(Table4[[#All],[MGRS]], MATCH(L583,Table4[[#All],[EMPS]],0))"

 End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

I feel that something is definitely wrong with the index match formula as the match cell "L583" is not moving to the next cell each time it runs through the loop; however, I am not sure how to fix it. I also do not know what else is potentially missing. The code currently executes, but it stays stuck on one cell.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I will make sure to clarify if necessary. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to better define your problem. First, and to check your claim that the loop does not advance, add a breakpoint at the first `If` within the loop and check the value of `cell` (or simply use a message window to display the address of it as `cell.Address()`. Second, you claim that `L583` is not changing. Why should it change if you are using a _literal value_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are only setting the formula for the `ActiveCell`.

```
ActiveCell.Formula = _
"=INDEX(Table4[[#All],[MGRS]], MATCH(L583,Table4[[#All],[EMPS]],0))"
```

This should fix it

```
cell.Formula = _
"=INDEX(Table4[[#All],[MGRS]], MATCH(L583,Table4[[#All],[EMPS]],0))"
```

You'll probably need to adjust `L583`.  It will not fill correctly unless you are filling across all cell.

These ranges should probably be changed so that they are dynamic.

```
Set FillRng = Range("J2:J2000")
Set FillRng1 = Range("K2:K2000")
```

You should apply the formula to all the cells in the range

> Range("K2:K2000").Formula = "=INDEX(Table4[[#All],[MGRS]], MATCH(L2,Table4[[#All],[EMPS]],0))"

### UPDATE: Dynamic Range

Every table in Excel should have at least one column that contain an entry for every record in the table.  This column should be used to define the height of the Dynamic Range.

For instance if Column A always has entries and you want to create a Dynamic Range for Column K

```
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = Range("K2:K" & lastrow)
```

Or

```
Set rng1 = Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 10)
```

### UPDATE:

Use `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` to target the blank cells. You'll have to add an Error handler because `SpecialCells` will throw an Error if no blank cells were found.

[image]

```
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 10).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "There were no Blank Cels Found", vbInformation, "Action Cancelled"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: I was looking for a quick and easy way to locate and match all empty cells in column J and K, which your suggestion adequately provides - thanks! In regards to dynamic ranges, could you kindly provide guidance or a resource that would help teach me that logic. I am fairly new to data mining in Excel so I appreciate it.

Comment: Your update worked, and the lesson on dynamic ranges is much appreciated. A follow-up question: is there a way to run the IndexMatch formula only in blank cells while ignoring cells with text?

Comment: Hi Thomas Inzina. Since you have been the most helpful to me in my Excel VBA project, I was hoping you could answer a question I had in regards to using a reference range to highlight cells in an adjacent table.

Comment: Okay  @J.Woe. What is it?

Comment: I am attempting to annotate rows of data on a table (Table 1). It will be at random, based on two criterias from a separate table (Table 2). 
Table 1 has two columns; Column A which will have a "Check" word coded to be populated randomly based on criteria from Table 2, and Column B which has different names down the rows, some of which could be duplicates. 
Table 2's Column A will have all the names in Table 1 de-duplicated, and their Column B will have a number which indicates the number of rows to be annotated in Table 1 - based on a match between Table 1's Column B and Table 2's Column A.

Comment: I am at a standstill with this and sincerely appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: @J.Woe Sorry that I haven't got back to you before now.  I'm not quite sure what you mean.  If you email me a sample workbook at tommy70458@gmail.com I'll look it over.  I'm pretty busy right now, you'll probably get a quicker response by posting the Question to SO.  If you do please send me the link.

Answer (score 0):

The "L583" was not changing because you were not telling it to. The code below should change the reference as the cell address changes.

[Range.Address Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx)

```
Sub FillVPs()
Dim FillRng As Range, FillRng1 As Range, cell As Range

Set FillRng = Range("J2:J2000")
Set FillRng1 = Range("K2:K2000")

For Each cell In FillRng1
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Formula = _
    "=INDEX(Table4[[#All],[MGRS]], MATCH(" & cell.Offset(0,1).Address() & ",Table4[[#All],[EMPS]],0))"

 End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell` should be changed to `cell` and  `cell.Address()` need to be changed to `cell.Offset(0 ,1).Address()`

Comment: Hello Craig T, I have inputted your code. Thank you for the help, but I am running into a Type Error Mismatch (13) once I get to the 'For Each' statement. Another factor I did not mention was that column J as well as K is not completely empty, so I would have to disregard those cells, only IndexMatching ones that are empty. Does the code encompass that issue?